# Background image behind the installer window with NSIS

Tags: image, background, nsis

I'm doing an installer with NSIS.

How can I put a background image behind the installer window?

I want the users not to be able to do anything but the installation.
So far, I only have found how to put a background image in the installer window.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the [classic blue gradient window](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=63564) from the Windows 3/95 era with `BGGradient`:

```
BGGradient
```

or

```
BGGradient 0000FF 000000 FFFFFF ; Blue to black gradient, white text
```

If you use the [BgImage plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/BgImage/BgImage.txt) you can also add custom images and multiple text entries.

This background window does not fully prevent the user from doing anything else (
<kbd>Alt</kbd>
+
<kbd>Tab</kbd>
 etc.) but that would be evil because it is their computer, not yours!